# Select query while grouping with ActiveRecord does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following query in my backend:

```
@books = Book.select("city, sum(rating)").group("city")
```

The table in the database is as follows:

```
  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.string "city"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_books_on_author_id"
  end
```

The result that I get is as follows:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Book id: nil, city: "barcelona">, #<Book id: nil, city: "madrid">]>
```

I am using sqlite, just to practice AR.

In sqlite, the command that I would use shows the results that I expect:

```
sqlite> SELECT city, sum(rating) FROM books GROUP BY city;
city        sum(rating)
----------  -----------
barcelona   11         
madrid      10
```

- Why am I not seeing the sum of the ratings with ActiveRecord?
- Why am I seeing the ids, if I didn't select them?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the ids because `inspect` is not perfect in ActiveRecord.

You're not seeing the sum of the ratings because `inspect` is not perfect in ActiveRecord.

If you add an `AS` to your `select`:

```
@books = Book.select("city, sum(rating) AS rating_sum").group("city")
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Book id: nil, city: "barcelona">, #<Book id: nil, city: "madrid">]>
@books.first.rating_sum
# => 11
```

you will be able to call `.rating_sum` on each of the returned elements, but you still won't see the sum in your console when inspecting an element.

In this case, you may also access the sum without using `AS` by calling `.sum` on your results,

```
@books.first.sum
```

but once your query gets more complex, you will need to specify the attribute names explicitly by using `AS` in your query.

As you've probably noticed, the ids you are seeing are null, it's because `inspect` for ActiveRecord always displays id of a model and since your query hasn't returned it, nothing is assigned to it.

Comment: But in the documentation there is this option: 
`Order.select("date(created_at) as ordered_date, sum(price) as total_price").group("date(created_at)")`. Does your answer mean, that I have to use raw SQL in Rails for this purpose?

Comment: No, you simply would not see `ordered_date` and `total_price` because they're not printed in rails console, as `inspect` does not work this way for ActiveRecord objects. But you still can access these methods, as I've shown above.

Comment: Oh I see, AR creates an instance method (attr_reader), with the name that you put after the AS, that's why the AS is important. Wow, I read the whole documentation  and didn't find that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Technically, it's not an `attr_reader` and no instance variable is set, but you still get the method.